# How many different four letter words can be formed (the words need not be meaningful) using the letters of the word “MEDITERRANEAN” ...

Tags: combinatorics

How many different four letter words can be formed (the words need not be meaningful) using the letters of the word “MEDITERRANEAN” such that the first letter is E and the last letter is R?
A) 59
B) 11! / (3!*2!*2!*2!)
C) 11! / (2!*2!*2!)
D) 23
E) 56

Comment: We have four letters but two of them are constrained. There are eight distinct numbers in the word "mediterranean": a, d, e, i, m, n, r and t. If we do not care that the words should be meaningful we can choose the middle letters as any of these eight, but we must remember that if the two middle letters are the same then we will be counting these twice. So we should correct for this

Comment: I think they are repetitive permutations.

Comment: Make two cases: one where the middle letters are the same, and the other in which they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Lets divide the word into pools.

$P_1=E,E,E,R,R$

$P_2=M,D,I,T,A,N,A,N$

Now for every $4$ letter word $E$ and $R$ are fixed. So we have to fill the remaining $2$ spots with other letters.

Case $1$: The other two letters are distinct

There are $8$ distinct letters, and choosing a pair of $2$ like $EM, RE, MI$ etc

$$\binom{8}{2}\cdot 2!=56$$

Case $2$: The other two letters are same

If the two middle letters are same, then
only $E,A,N$ can be the middle letters.

$$\binom{3}{1}=3$$

Adding up case $1$ and case $2$

$$56+3=59$$

Comment: Not so sure to understand what you do. Where comes from the $\binom{3}{1}$ ? Also, I don't have the impression that you consider words of the form $EEMR$. Also, when you say the letter of the middle are the same or not the same, is compare to what ? $E$ and $R$ ? Or words of the form $ENNR$ for case 2 and $EERR$ for case 1 ? Of $ENNR$ for case 1 and EERR for case 2 ? (this is not so clear in what you wrote).

Comment: I have editted my post for clarity

Answer (score 1):

After the **E** and **R** are placed, the remaining letters are:

> **M,D,I,T,E,R,A,N,E,A,N**

This is $8$ distinct letters in total, **M,D,I,T,E,R,A,N**, with two of each of **E,A,N**.

If there were two of every letter, we would have $8\times8=64$ possibilities, but we cannot have a repeated **M,D,I,T,R**, so the final answer is $64-5=59$.